# Java - Need advice on how to unit test this class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm not very experienced when it comes to constructing unit tests or test cases, and right now I'm in need of some advice. I have this class that I'm planning to make, but I'm not sure what the best way of unit testing it would be. I have not written the class yet but it will look something like this:

```
public class ClassName {

    private ArrayList<Order> sortedOrderList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Order> sortedOrderList2 = new ArrayList<>();

    public void method1(Order order) {
      //Modifies Order objects inside sortedOrderList1 or sortedOrderList2.
    }

    public method2(Order order) {
      //Modifies Order objects inside sortedOrderList1 or sortedOrderList1.
    }
}
```

The `Order` objects inside the lists have `price` and `quantity`. The methods will go into the lists and subtract from `quantity` for some of the Order objects at the end of the lists, and also remove objects whose `quantity` has reached 0.

Now the problem is that I don't know what the best way of testing these methods would be. In my JUnit class I won't be able to access the `private` lists, and the methods themselves have no return value for me to check. What would be the best practice way of testing methods like these?

Comment: How are you setting the `sortedOrderList1` and `sortedOrderList2` ?

Comment: You gotta think about where these orders come from and where they go to. They aren't just created internally and never see the light of day, right?

Comment: A better question may is what are you trying to do? Sometimes when unit tests are difficult to write it means you should refactor your code. In some cases it can be helpfull to write your tests first (this defines clearly what you are trying to do). Then write code that makes those tests pass. See TDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create unit tests for both of those public methods. If these methods make changes on the order object they are passed as parameter then your unit test should have assertions on that object. Also you should check the state of the sortedOrderLists.

You will have a little bit problem to get hold on those sorted order lists to check them. Here are three possible solutions.

The first option if for some reason you cannot or do not want to change your class implementation. You will have to use reflection to get references to those private fields.

The second option is to change the visibility of those fields to protected. Then create the unit test class in the same package. Now it is straight forward to get hold of those sorted order lists.

The third and probably best option is to use dependency injection for those fields. There are many different options for dependency injection. You could use CDI or Spring something like that. But to keep it simple you could just use plain java setter or constructor injection. Just do not new those lists up inside your class. Since you inject those lists, now they can even be private. Your unit test class will create the lists and inject them in your class under test. Now you have a reference on those private fields and can use assertions to check them.

Example with constructor injection:

```
public class ClassName {

    private ArrayList<Order> sortedOrderList1;
    private ArrayList<Order> sortedOrderList2;

    public ClassName(ArrayList<Order> sortedOrderList1, ArrayList<Order> sortedOrderList2) {
        this.sortedOrderList1 = sortedOrderList1;
        this.sortedOrderList2 = sortedOrderList2;
    }

    public void method1(Order order) {
      //Modifies Order objects inside sortedOrderList1 or sortedOrderList2.
    }

    public method2(Order order) {
      //Modifies Order objects inside sortedOrderList1 or sortedOrderList1.
    }
}
```

Example unit test:

```
import org.junit.Assert;

public class ClassNameTest {

    public void testMethod1() {
        ArrayList<Order> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Order> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        Order order = new Order();
        ClassName testMe = new ClassName(list1, list2);
        testMe.method1(order);
        // Insert your assertions for example:
        Assert.assertTrue(list1.contains(order));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the class as you've described it does nothing else then you may as well not unit test it as it's useless.  For your code to be useful it must either return a value, change state or possible both.  In your example you're modifying state so your test needs to verify that state change has happened correctly.  Now you must be modifying the state in order to achieve something, i.e. another method returns that data or it gets sent somewhere - *this* is how you unit test your code.

**UPDATE**

Based on more information from the OP there is a method to print the orders to STDOUT.  This qualifies as the *side effect* function I mentioned above.  In this case you would want to provide an abstraction over STDOUT that you can mock/fake from your test and then verify that the updated orders make their way to that correctly.

Comment: This is a command line application and the methods are going to print the modifications they make to the lists to stdout. The user can enter a command to have all orders printed, or they can enter a command to add or remove quantity to/from an order. So the only place where data is sent/outputted is to stdout.

Comment: In that case the test is letting you know something about your design (also that information would be useful in the original post).   I'll update my answer to reflect this